# Dropzonejs - manipulate DOM in previewTemplate of single image

Tags: dropzone.js

I want to be able to select a single element within the previewtemplate of a single image, such as:

```
//I'm passing the file to the function
MyDropzone.on('complete', function(file){

       // select e.g. the .dz-success-mark for this file and make it visible
         myselectedelement.css('display', 'block');
}
```

I am passing `file`, but how do I get the `.dz-success-mark` within the template of that `file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your DOM node this way (jquery example)

```html
MyDropzone.on('complete', function(file){
         $(file.previewElement).css('display', 'block');
}
```

Comment: God, you asked this 7 months ago xD

Comment: Yes but I had abandoned that project for now, however I will still have to finish it in the future so I still find it useful!